# Fetch Database Value to multiple textboxes based on dropdown value in php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to populate textbox values automatically from DB based on dropdown selection.....I have tried this, but after selecting dropdown the page is refreshing but the values are not populated onto textbox....need Help!!

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3TxP.jpg)

Controller:

```
    public function isrexpense()
    {
    $data['query'] = $this->Isr_model->getstates();
    $data['names'] = $this->Isr_model->getAllNames();
    $data['query1'] = $this->Isr_model->test();
    $this->load->view("header"); 
    $this->load->view('Isr/isrexpense', $data);
    $this->load->view("footer");
    }
```

Model:

```
    function test()
    {
    $this->db->select('da_hq');
    $this->db->from('isr_policy_master');
    $this->db->where('state', $this->input->post('state'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }
```

View:

```
 <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
 <?php 
 foreach($names as $row)
 { 
 echo '<option></option>';
 echo '<option value="'.$row->name.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
 }
 ?>
 </select> 
 <select class="state form-control" id="state" name="state">
 <?php 
 foreach($query as $row)
 { 
 echo '<option value="'.$row->state_code.'">'.$row->state_name.'</option>';
 } ?>  
 </select>  


 <script>
 $('#state').on('change', function(){
 var mainselection = this.value; // get the selection value
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",  // method of sending data
 url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Isr/isrexpense",
 data:'selection='+mainselection,
 success: function(result)
 {
 $("#hqda").html(result);
  }
 });
 });
 </script>


 <input id="hqda" name="hqda" class="form-control" required type="number">
```

Comment: Replace `data:'selection='+mainselection,` with `data:{'selection':mainselection},`

Comment: Replace `$("#hqda").html(result);` with `$("#hqda").val(result);`

Comment: @Twinkle I replaced it ..... no changes, it's working same way :(

Comment: @SrujanRamannaGowda see my answer below - you need to check what your ajax call is actually returning. Also check if it's even succeeding or not (use your  browser's Developer Tools to do that). I don't know if your isrexpense() model accepts post requests, and it also seems that it potentially doesn't accept any input data - the method has no parameters.

Comment: @ADyson Ok sir, i'm bit new to ajax so i'm finding it difficult....i'll debug and get back to you

Answer (score 3):

Controller :

```
            public function isrexpense()
            {
                $data['query'] = $this->Isr_model->getstates();
                $data['names'] = $this->Isr_model->getAllNames();
                $this->load->view("header"); 
                $this->load->view('Isr/isrexpense', $data);
                $this->load->view("footer");
            }

            public function getValFromDb()
            {
                $state = $this->input->post('selection');
                $query1 = $this->Isr_model->test($state);
                echo json_encode(array('data'=>$query1));
            }
```

Model:

```
            function test($state)
            {
                $this->db->select('da_hq');
                $this->db->from('isr_policy_master');
                $this->db->where('state', $state);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $result = $query->result();
                if(count($result)>0)
                {
                    return $result[0]['da_hq'];
                }
                else
                {
                    return '';
                }
            }
```

View :

```
            <script>
             $('#state').on('change', function(){
             var mainselection = this.value; // get the selection value
             $.ajax({
             type: "POST",  // method of sending data
             url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Isr/getValFromDb",
             data:'selection='+mainselection,
             success: function(result)
             {
                console.log(result); // check this in your console and if require than use JSON.parse to get value
                $("#hqda").val(result.data);
              }
             });
             });
             </script>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in E:\xampp\htdocs\SFA_test\application\models\Isr_model.php:116 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\SFA_test\application\controllers\Isr.php(86): Isr_model->test(false) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\SFA_test\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): Isr->getValFromDb() #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\SFA_test\index.php(204): require_once('E:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\SFA_test\application\models\Isr_model.php on line 116

Comment: Try $query->result_array(); instead of $query->result(); in model test function

Comment: have you got the solution or not ?

Comment: @Coolbuddy No i cleared the above mentioned error but not getting the result..... Nothings happening after selecting state from drop down

Answer (score 0):

Textboxes don't have an "innerHTML" property. If you want to set the content of a textbox, you should set its *value* property. In jQuery you do this using the `.val()` method.

Replace

```
$("#hqda").html(result);
```

with

```
$("#hqda").val(result);
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

and http://api.jquery.com/val/

P.S. You may also want to take a look at what your AJAX call returns - it's not clear whether it would return the content you're looking for or not - it appears to return a whole HTML view, rather than just a single value to place into a textbox.

Comment: Oh i was not knowing that, i made the changes but still it works same...

Comment: @SrujanRamannaGowda see my comment on the main question. If nothing appears to be happening then you need to start debugging to see if the code is running as you expected, and what it is producing (if anything)

Comment: i tried debugging, In XHR i don't see any activity after selecting state dropdown....

Comment: in Ajax function i replaced .on with .live , now i see some activity in XHR but its not passing any parameter ,.... i think ajax call is fine now,but not passing any parameter with it

Comment: you replaced .on() with .live()? Why would you do that? .on() replaced .live() in jQuery 1.7, and now .live() is deprecated. It's like you're stepping back in time. Unless you have a very old version of jQuery you shouldn't need to do that. See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Anyway your information is too vague really to let me help you. Based on the code you've written, it should pass a parameter called "mainselection" in the ajax query. Can you add screenshots of your network tab showing what you actually see right now?

Comment: Hey, yes you are right i was using very old jquery version... now changed to 2.2.0 and using .on() itself...But i don't see any activity in XHR, please check the screenshot below

Comment: Please Check this link https://i.postimg.cc/rw9d469C/Capture1.jpg I'm getting this error now

Comment: I don't know where (because I don't know your line numbers) but it means that somewhere in your PHP you've got a variable which is an object/class, but you're trying to do something to it which can only be done to arrays.

Comment: public function getValFromDb()
{
    $state = $this->input->post('selection');
    $query1 = $this->Isr_model->test($state);
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$query1));
}

Comment: The line in which i'm getting error is this in model:return $result[0]['da_hq'];

Comment: well, I can't see your data, but it seems clear that either $result or $result[0] is a class object and you can't treat it like an array by asking for a sub-item using the `[]` syntax. Instead you'd have to ask for the property name using `->` syntax.

Comment: Well it WORKED!! I used this in ajax, var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);